# Tricky Sum involving Binomial Coefficients and Sine

Tags: trigonometry, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am stumped by the sum
$$\sum_{x=0}^n \binom{n}{x}\sin\big(\frac{\pi x}{n}\big)$$
but I can't figure it out. I tried expanding the taylor series of sine and using Euler's identity, but to no avail. Any hints?

**PLEASE** do not give me a full solution - I just need a hint.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $\sin \theta = \mathrm{Im} \: e^{i\theta}$. Forgive me if this is too big of spoiler! But, well, how could I have said any less?

Answer (score -3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{x = 0}^{n}{n \choose x}\sin\pars{\pi x \over n} & =
\Im\sum_{x = 0}^{n}{n \choose x}\expo{\ic\pi x/n} =
\Im\sum_{x = 0}^{n}{n \choose x}\pars{\expo{\ic\pi/n}}^{x} =
\Im\pars{1 + \expo{\ic\pi/n}}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\Im\bracks{1 + \cos\pars{\pi \over n} + \ic\sin\pars{\pi \over n}}^{\,n}
\\[5mm] & =
\Im\bracks{\root{2 + 2\cos\pars{\pi \over n}}
\exp\pars{\ic\arctan\pars{\sin\pars{\pi/n} \over 1 + \cos\pars{\pi/n}}}}^{\,n}
\\[5mm] & =
2^{n/2}\,\bracks{2\cos^{2}\pars{\pi \over 2n}}^{\,n/2}\
\sin\pars{n\arctan\pars{2\sin\pars{\pi/\bracks{2n}}\cos\pars{\pi/\bracks{2n}} \over 2\cos^{2}\pars{\pi/\bracks{2n}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
2^{n}\,\verts{\cos\pars{\pi \over 2n}}^{\,n}
\sin\pars{n\arctan\pars{\tan\pars{\pi \over 2n}}}
\\[5mm] & =
2^{n}\,\verts{\cos\pars{\pi \over 2n}}^{\,n}\sin\pars{\pi \over 2} =
\bbx{2^{n}\,\verts{\cos\pars{\pi \over 2n}}^{\,n}} \\ &
\end{align}

Comment: The OP specifically asked: "**PLEASE** do not give me a full solution - I just need a hint."

Comment: @Hamed Thanks for that!

Comment: @FelixMarin Please delete your answer. I just asked for a hint, and besides that, it is barely comprehensible. Besides, I came up with a proof of my own involving the identity
$$(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta$$

Comment: while yes, FelixMarin probably shouldn't have posted the entire solution - it's still comprehensible.  Though it can be shortened significantly by observing...$$\operatorname{Im}{{\left( 1+{{e}^{i\pi /n}} \right)}^{n}}=\operatorname{Im}{{\left( {{e}^{-i\pi /2n}}+{{e}^{i\pi /2n}} \right)}^{n}}{{e}^{-i\pi /2}}=...$$