# Find expression for following summation

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

> Find expression of:
>   $$
> \sum_{r=1}^n \dbinom{n}{r} \sin {r\theta}  = ???
> $$

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371738/tricky-sum-involving-binomial-coefficients-and-sine

Comment: Write as two sums involving complex exponentials and consider the Binomial expansion

Comment: Perhaps the recursion
$$
\sin r\theta = 2\cos\theta\sin((r-1)\theta)-\sin((r-2)\theta)
$$
may help.

Answer (score 4):

> $$X=\sum_{r=1}^n \dbinom{n}{r} \sin {r\theta} = ?$$

Consider
$$\begin{align}
S:=\sum_{r=1}^n \dbinom{n}{r} e^{ir\theta}
&= \sum_{r=1}^n \dbinom{n}{r} (\underbrace{e^{i\theta}}_{:=a})^r \\
&= \sum_{r=1}^n \dbinom{n}{r} a^r \\
&= -1+\sum_{r=0}^n \dbinom{n}{r} a^r1^{n-r} \\
&= -1+(1+a)^n \\
&= (1+e^{i\theta})^n-1\\
\end{align}$$
Because $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$, we also have:
$$\begin{align}
S&= \sum_{r=1}^n \dbinom{n}{r} \big(\cos r\theta+i\sin r\theta\big) \\
&= \sum_{r=1}^n \dbinom{n}{r} \cos r\theta 
+ i\underbrace{\sum_{r=1}^n \dbinom{n}{r} \sin r\theta}_{=X} \\
\end{align}$$

> Hence: $\def\Im{\operatorname{Imag}}$
>   $$\begin{align}
> X&= \Im(S) \\
> &= \Im\big((1+e^{i\theta})^n-1\big) \\
> &= \Im\big((1+e^{i\theta})^n\big) 
> \end{align}$$
>   where $\Im$ denotes the imaginary part of a complex number.