# Sum with Binomial Coefficients and Sine; $S=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \sin(kx)$

Tags: trigonometry, summation, binomial-coefficients

### Sum with Binomial Coefficients

Let $n ∈ ℕ₀$ and $x ∈ ℝ$.

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}  \sin(kx)$$

Simplify the sum to a polynomial in n.

I tried to use Euler's Formula and the Binomial Theorem, similar to [Tricky Sum involving Binomial Coefficients and Sine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371738/tricky-sum-involving-binomial-coefficients-and-sine). Alas I could not fully understand the option presented. I would be grateful for an explanation or even better another way of approaching the problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos for providing the information. I will make sure to use it when writing successive posts!

Comment: And I appreciate @HeroZhang001 editing the mistakes, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have;

> $$S=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} sin(kx)$$

I can think of two methods;

Method [1];

We can begin with $k=0,1,2,\cdots$ and consequently one can find a pattern and you will observe; $$S=2^nsin\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)cos^n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Method [2];

From Euler's Identity; $e^{ix}=isinx+cosx$, substitute $Sin(kx)= Im(e^{ikx})$,
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} Im(e^{ikx})$$
$$S=Im \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (e^{ix})^k\right)$$

$$S=Im \left(1+e^{ix}\right)^n$$

$$S=Im \left(isinx+cosx+1\right)^n$$

$$S=Im \left(isinx+2cos^2\frac{x}{2}\right)^n$$

$$S=Im \left(2isin\frac{x}{2}cos\frac{x}{2}+2cos^2\frac{x}{2}\right)^n$$

$$S=2^nIm \left(isin\frac{x}{2}cos\frac{x}{2}+cos^2\frac{x}{2}\right)^n$$

$$S=2^n\,Im \left(e^{\frac{inx}{2}}cos^n\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Using De Moivre theorem, and you can conclude here with

> $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} sin(kx)=2^nsin\left(\frac{nx}{2}\right)cos^n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$

Extras - $cos2x=2cos^2x-1, sin2x=2sinxcosx$

Comment: you could also get shorter $1+e^{ix}=e^{ix/2}(e^{-ix/2}+e^{ix/2})=2e^{ix/2}\cos(x/2)$.

Comment: Thank you @Ercanayan for the solution provided!

Comment: And thanks to @Lutz Lehmann for giving a quicker solution.